# C# int for hours and minutes, custom AddMinute Method

Tags: c#, time, model, integer

I have a custom time model with an Integer for hours and an Integer for minutes, seconds.
The class has an AddMinute(int value) method and I want that e.g....

```
CustomTime myTime = new CustomTime();
myTime.AddMinute(75);
```

...the minutes are added as Hours += 1 and Minutes += 15.

I have the solution myself, but am currently looking for the shortest possible one that does this
Does anyone know a good one?

Comment: `Hours += value / 60; Minutes += value % 60;`?

Comment: @RenéVogt: Not sufficient. It needs a `while (Minutes >= 60) {Hours+=1;Minutes-=60}` afterwards.

Comment: hm yeah but the following would end in 00:65
```
CustomTime myTime = new CustomTime();
myTime.AddMinute(30);
myTime.AddMinute(35);
```

Comment: Any particular reason you are reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Yeah definitely. I know the ready-made DateTime and TimeSpan functions, but I need it to be done with my custom class :)

Comment: @Lucas the have a look at my edited answer

Comment: @PMF why? for `value = 60` my code increases `Hours` by 1 and `Minutes` by zero. And for 75 it adds 1 and 15, because `(int)75/60` is `1` and `(int)75%60` is `15`. Why would I need your loop afterwards?

Comment: @RenéVogt: Because if Minute is previously already at 59, adding something requires another carry-over.

Comment: @PMF right, missed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your current class the best answer I think is what René Vogt mentioned in the comments:

```
Hours += (value + Minutes) / 60;
Minutes = (value + Minutes) % 60;
```

However I don't see a point in reinventing the wheel, You can use `TimeSpan` struct instead of your own `CustomTime` class, which already have all these options, and not only adding seconds, minutes, ... you can add/subtract another time and more:

[TimeSpan Struct (Microsoft Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-5.0)

Comment: ty, thats what i needed!

Comment: About the `However I don't see a point in reinventing the wheel` I present to you https://nodatime.org/ which reinvented the wheel :)

Comment: Well I thought like you except that if resulting minutes becomes 60+ then we must do a -60 and add 1 more to hours, `(value + Minutes) / 60` and `(value + Minutes) % 60` do this